# Resize an image to square resolution

Tags: android, image

I am developing an android application which resizes android pictures. I was wondering if its possible to resize a file with resolution (1080X1920) to (500X500) **square size**.

Without looking too **bad** (quality and dimensions).

Let me show you an ***example***.

**First image:**

[image]

**Resized picture:**

[image]

Answers using code will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to distort the image you have two options:

- Crop the image
- Implement the [seam carving algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving)

**Edit**: this assumes you want to fill up the whole square. If not, just keep the width/height ratio and downscale the image properly so that the largest dimension fits in the side of the square.

Comment: actually i want to avoid cropping the image

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you show me a piece of code where i can start?

Comment: I don't know of any library that implements the algorithm, but it shouldn't be difficult to find on google. Just try "seam carving java". My first link for example is an implementation in Swing.